# How can we upload file through SCP in python (By only python core inbuild package , no extra package to be install)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess, scp

I see lot of example of file transfer in python, i don't find proper answer how to upload file through inbuild python libaray.

We can use some package like.

```
import os
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient
```

But this are package not inbuild by default in python.

Also I have check inbuild package `subprocess` , but it doesn't take password because looks like `scp` don't take password from command.

Is there is a way to upload file to server in python by scp or ssh with password to be pass somewher in python code ?

Comment: Generally, you would use either key-based authentication, pexpect, or paramiko. But it seems like your design constraints exclude all three solutions. Can you talk about why you can't use a package not built into Python?

Comment: So looks like python is there in system and i can not install any other package, So if possible in core library that would be fine. Otherwise i know  addition package i can do, but not preferred.